# How do you control sidebars when there's no get_sidebar in templates?

Tags: sidebar

I'm working with a WordPress 4.0 install, using Omega (the ThemeHall version; there are multiple Omega themes out there).

Most of the instructions I've seen to control whether the sidebar appears or not tell me to work with the `get_sidebar` tag.

This theme lets me turn the sidebar on everywhere or nowhere, so I've opted to turn it on universally so I can find, and remove, get_sidebar from page templates.

But when I look at *all* the .php files in the main theme folder, get_sidebar doesn't appear. Anywhere. Not in page.php, index.php, footer.php, etc. etc. etc.

This is where my WordPress-understanding-powers come to a screeching halt. If get_sidebar isn't in the page templates, where is it?

This is a typical page structure in the theme; this is page.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package Omega
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <main  class="<?php echo omega_apply_atomic( 'main_class', 'content' );?>" <?php omega_attr( 'content' ); ?>>

        <?php 
        do_action( 'omega_before_content' ); 

        do_action( 'omega_content' ); 

        do_action( 'omega_after_content' ); 
        ?>

    </main><!-- .content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In the absence of get_sidebar (and with sidebars turned on everywhere, I thought get_sidebar would appear *somewhere* in these templates), what's the best way of controlling which templates get sidebars and which don't?

Comment: Do you have an understanding of hooks/actions? What have Omega support said? Can you link to it? Omega is a pretty common word

Comment: Hooks and actions? I think we may have found my problem. No idea. Forums for Omega are at http://themehall.com/forums.

Comment: You will need an understanding of how actions and hooks work to understand how this theme functions.

Comment: I'd best get to reading...

Answer (score 1):

In the ThemeHall Omega theme, the call to `get_sidebar` is wrapped in a function called `omega_primary_sidebar`. This can be found in `hooks.php` lines 180 to 185. This function then gets hooked to the `omega_after_main` action hook on line 35 and 36 in the same file

Comment: Thanks -- I'm able to manage to remove the sidebar from some areas with this information. It still formats the pages as though the sidebar was there, though... I think I'm going to have to really dig into action hooks to "get" this.

Comment: I believe, like the bundled themes, this is manipulated by body classes. I will look into that later if you haven't yet found a solution to this.